# SQL Finding duplicates of group Column A and ColumnB where Count in C

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

This may have actually been posted but the recommended questions did not show any light and finding the correct words for the title was a task itself.

Given these 3 columns I am trying to find the correct SQL Query to manage duplicates under specific conditions:

```
ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC
---------------------------
   1    |    1    |   A
   1    |    2    |   A
   2    |    2    |   B
   2    |    2    |   A
   2    |    2    |   B
   1    |    2    |   B
```

So my counter is supposed to be the count of occurrences - condition of C
The rule is that ColumnA can be assigned to the number of ColumnB where ColumnC is A or B and that counts as 1. If ColumnA is assigned to the number of ColumnB and has a second A or B in ColumnC then that counts as 2. (1/1/A 1/1/B = 1) (1/1/A 1/1/A = 2).

Following this the above table equals 4:

- 1/1/A = 1

  1/2/A = 1

  2/2/B = 1

  2/2/A = 0

  2/2/B = 1

  1/2/B = 0

In C# I have done some management for storing values and comparing enumerators to check against this

```
//If the hash table fails to add due to a duplicate then thats a second count of it existing (and breaks the rule of 1 per A and B
if(!hash.Add(new Tuple<int, int, ColumnType>(itemA.ColumnA, itemA.ColumnB, itemA.ColumnC)))
{
    count++;
}
else
{
    //If the table contains the counter part (so if this is 1/1/A is there a 1/1/B)
    if(hash.Contains(new Tuple<int, int, ColumnType>(itemA.ColumnA, itemA.ColumnB, (itemA.ColumnC == ColumnType.A ? ColumnType.B : ColumnType.A))))
    {
        //There is so take a point off as thats allowed
        count--;
    }
    else
    {
        //The item was added to the hash table normally and theres no counter part
        count++;
    }
}
```

Of course I am looking into improving efficiency, the use of the hash set is the replacement for another class that purely works on adding and iterating through a dictionary which was slower. This is faster then that and I am assuming straight referencing a count through SQL Command is going to be faster still.

Comment: alphabetic incremented value in columns names are suspect and a good candidate for normalisation.

Comment: @RaymondNijland while this is true, I assume (and hope) OP used those names for the example only

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, just for the example, they are int | int | string and the ints represent ID's.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
int count = YourTable.GroupBy(x=> new {x.ColumnA, x.ColumnB, x.ColumnC})
.Select(g => g.Key)
.Distinct()
.Count();
```

Comment: My other class uses this for the dictionary version but it is slow and returns an incorrect count unfortunately. (This gives 191 where the expected is 202).
As mentioned it is mostly an attempt to improve the current code by displaying the use of SQL to simply query the counts without the need for memory storage or algorithms to manage those counters

Comment: @Tyndareus are you sure? because the count can not be incorrect.